# TensorFlow model with custom prediction routine on GCP

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

Well I am using the AI Platform to deploy a LSTM based tensorflow model on GCP. I have trained and tested model on local machine. The model goes as follows:

```
lookback = 16
lstm_input = Input(shape=(1, look_back), name='lstm_input')
x = LSTM(250, name='lstm_0')(lstm_input)
...
x = Dense(1, name='dense_3')(x)
```

The model is intended to predict one value at a time based on previous 16 values. But in practice I do need 16 values as prediction. I made this possible locally by appending the predicted value at the end of original ones and then perform prediction again till I have 16 values as follows:

```
def predict(num_prediction, model):
    prediction_list = list(total_data.iloc[-look_back-1:])

    for _ in range(num_prediction):
        x = np.array(prediction_list[-look_back:])
        x = x.reshape((1, 1, look_back)) #(152, 1, 15)
        out = model.predict(x)
        prediction_list.append(out)
    prediction_list = prediction_list[look_back-1:]

    return prediction_list
```

Plus I also did normalize the data locally and have the mean and std values on board while training and prediction. I have exported them to a json file and uploaded it to the GCP alongside with my model (.pb) file

So everything works locally. But I am unable to do this on GCP as I am no sure how to denormalize using my own parameters and do recursive predictions like that. I am trying to make use of custom prediction routine to achieve that task but even simple predictions do not work once model is deployed over there as prediction. As I have formatted my input perfectly as guided over [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict?hl=en_US#formatting_your_input_for_online_prediction) :

```
{"instances":[ [[[-1.11942447, -1.22374662, -0.46512613,  2.32171842,
          0.93306964,  0.71291355,  1.74912453,  1.2969071 ,
          0.18740628,  1.20175769,  1.08269237,  0.29160862,
          0.84450949,  2.34316635,  1.11384735,  0.65933734]]] ]}
```

but it throws following error while predicting:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:\n\tstatus = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT\n\tdetails = \"transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3\n\t [[{{node model_4/lstm_0/transpose}}]]\"\n\tdebug_error_string = \"{\"created\":\"@1587901568.938325490\",\"description\":\"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8081\",\"file\":\"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc\",\"file_line\":1056,\"grpc_message\":\"transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3\\n\\t [[{{node model_4/lstm_0/transpose}}]]\",\"grpc_status\":3}\"\n>"
}
```

So this appeared to be a shape issue and I might have to increase the dimensions but adding another pair of brackets only worsen the thing with following error:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:\n\tstatus = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT\n\tdetails = \"transpose expects a vector of size 5. But input(1) is a vector of size 3\n\t [[{{node model_4/lstm_0/transpose}}]]\"\n\tdebug_error_string = \"{\"created\":\"@1588177916.982978933\",\"description\":\"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8081\",\"file\":\"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc\",\"file_line\":1056,\"grpc_message\":\"transpose expects a vector of size 5. But input(1) is a vector of size 3\\n\\t [[{{node model_4/lstm_0/transpose}}]]\",\"grpc_status\":3}\"\n>"
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** Able to get prediction for a single value now by giving it 3 brackets only. That worked. But still struggling with recursive predictions and denormalization.

Comment: The input you are giving is of size 3 and it is complaining it should be 4, have you tried adding another layer of "[ ]"? Could you anyway provide more information about your input processing? Why is it formatted with an apparently unnecessary high rank (input[0][0][0] = [] instead of input = [])?

Comment: Yeah cause its a forecast problem 1st axis represent how many examples in train/ test sets other two are (lookback, 1) to make each example a single input. Plus adding this extra bracket does not help either

Comment: do you think you could provide with full code for further debugging? Did the error message change somehow with the extra braket?

Comment: Thanks @Albert Albesa that helped me a bit closer. Updated the question

Comment: You are welcome, can what is the current debugging situation now? Are you facing some other error or it comes to conceptual issues?

Comment: Able to get prediction for a single value now by giving it 3 brackets only. That worked. But still struggling with recursive predictions and denormalization

Comment: Have you tried to implement a processing like your [def predict] within a custom prediction routine? Have you already faced any issues trying to implement that?

Comment: @User5: Is your issue resolved now? Else, you can try using `inputs` instead of `instances`.

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors that particular issue has been resolved. Though struggling with custom prediction routine for recursive predictions

Comment: @User5: Ok.. did you try 
`{"instances":[ [[[-1.11942447, -1.22374662, -0.46512613,  2.32171842,
          0.93306964,  0.71291355,  1.74912453,  1.2969071 ,
          0.18740628,  1.20175769,  1.08269237,  0.29160862,
          0.84450949,  2.34316635,  1.11384735,  0.65933734]]], [[[-1.11942447, -1.22374662, -0.46512613,  2.32171842,
          0.93306964,  0.71291355,  1.74912453,  1.2969071 ,
          0.18740628,  1.20175769,  1.08269237,  0.29160862,
          0.84450949,  2.34316635,  1.11384735,  0.65933734]]] ]}`.
Also, you can try replacing `instances` with `inputs`.